# want to take xml response value in a variable using CURL

Tags: php, xml, curl

i am hitting a URL/API in browser and getting below xml response from the server.

```
<test xmlns:taxInfoDto="com.message.TaxInformationDto">
  <response>
     <code>0000</code>
     <description>SUCCESS</description>
  </response>
  <accounts>
     <account currency="BDT" accAlias="6553720">
     <currentBalance>856.13</currentBalance>
     <availableBalance>856.13</availableBalance>
     </account>
  </accounts>
  <transaction>
     <principalAmount>0</principalAmount>
     <feeAmount>0.00</feeAmount>
     <transactionRef>2570277672</transactionRef>
     <externalRef/>
     <dateTime>09/03/2016</dateTime>
     <userName>01823074838</userName>
     <taxInformation totalAmount="0.00"/>
     <additionalData/>
     </transaction>
 </test>
```

i am using below php code to get the response....

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://x.x.x.x:/ussd/process?  destination=BANGLA&userName=&secondarySource=01");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$retValue = curl_exec($ch);
return $retValue;
?>
```

i am getting only value as a output like below.

```
0000SUCCESS856.13 856.13 00.00257027769109/03/201601823074838
```

But i like to assign every value in a variable and want to print it.
such as

```
code=0000
description=SUCCESS
currentBalance=856.13
```

anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking at the output of the cURL request in a browser: you need to escape your output to prevent the browser from interpreting it as HTML/XML, so apply `htmlentities` on the output before displaying it as in:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
....
return htmlentities($retValue);
```

Comment: still not getting the correct output...
Now getting below with previous result.
HTTP/1.1 200 OK X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 Server: Sun GlassFish Enterprise Server v2.1.1 Content-Type: text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1 Content-Length: 228 Date: Wed, 09 Mar 2016 07:58:04 GMT